# How to run a batch script which is on a server, but it should be run on a PC remotely

Tags: windows, script, batch, administrator

There are many batch scripts on one of our servers that are shared to everyone. These are scripts like Robocopying, portable apps, etc.

I am in tech support, and when someone asks me (for example) "I need LibreOffice on my PC.", I go to his PC and open the shared folder of the server, and run the specific script that is required.

Since I am an admin and know the PC name, username, password, and the path of the script which is on the server, can I do it remotely?

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. A lot of typos... and please use code indention. I tried to correct the typos, but gave up, because I was unsure what you want to express.

Answer (score 2):

Something like PSExec would do what you are asking...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx